# How to get rid of KWallet

Tags: kwallet

Tell us how we can easily to get rid of KWallet completely. Very bothersome app in my case, never use it, it just gets in the way.

Comment: How you "get rid of" an application depends entirely upon how you originally installed it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be clear about what `kwallet` you mean exactly (there appears to be some bitcoin wallet app with that name, as well as the kde local credentials storage app). Also include how you installed it and from where you got it, as well as what version of Ubuntu you are on.